# Reading TCP packets to and from a specific port in Python 3

Tags: python, wireshark, pyshark

I am trying to replicate the data I am seeing in Wireshark using this filter `tcp.port == 25565`. I have tried using socket and pyshark, however, I cannot seem to find a simple tutorial which explains how to do this.

As you can probably tell by the port, I am trying to decode Minecraft packets. Advice on how to get the payload and get a start on parsing that data would be very helpful.

So far, I have this code:

```py
from scapy.all import *

def test(pkt):
    print(pkt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    single = sniff(filter="tcp.port == 25565", prn=test)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `sniff(filter="tcp and port 25565", prn=test)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `sniff(filter="tcp port 25565", prn=test)`.

Look at the [scapy documentation](https://0xbharath.github.io/art-of-packet-crafting-with-scapy/scapy/sniffing/index.html).

> We can add filtering to capture only packets that are interesting to us. Use standard tcpdump/libpcap syntax:

That syntax is specified in the `pcap-filter` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pcap-filter).

> qualifiers restrict the match to a particular protocol.
> Possible protos are: ether, fddi, tr, wlan, ip, ip6, arp, rarp, decnet, tcp and udp. E.g., 'ether src foo', 'arp net 128.3', 'tcp port 21',

I don't think the syntax is well explained in it (or I'm not reading the right part), but as you can see, `tcp port 21` is a valid filter and what you're looking for. For an alternative syntax that uses an `and`, you'll see this further down:

> Primitives may be combined using:
> A parenthesized group of primitives and operators (parentheses are special to the Shell and must be escaped).
> Negation ('!' or 'not').
> Concatenation ('&&' or 'and').
> Alternation ('||' or 'or').

As you can see, your filter options (or primitives) should be grouped using an operator. In this case, you want both to be true, so you want `tcp and port 25565`, or alternatively, `tcp && port 25565`.